# Receive Django signals across different containers

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, django-signals

I'm currently working on a Django project and I have some issues handling signals across different containers.

I have a first container that is connected to a data pipeline upstream and populating Django's database. I have an other container for the backend itself and on which I am running the server. I would like to use the signal "post save" to signal one of my app that a new model instance has been saved. Thus, I use the next piece of code in my app to receive this signal and process the instance that has been saved.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Organization)
def index_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    connections.create_connection(hosts=['elasticsearch'])  
    instance.indexing()
```

This works perfectly if I create manually an Organization instance on the Django admin interface, but the signal is not received when I'm populating the database with my first container.

Here is a part of my docker-compose file with the two containers I described:

```
worker:
   build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
   command: ./run_celery.sh
   env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.workers
   volumes:
      - .:/app

web:
   restart: always
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
   hostname: web
   command: /app/run_web.sh
   env_file:
     - ./.envs/.local/.web
   volumes:
     - .:/app
   ports:
     - "80:8000"
   links:
     - db
     - pipeline_db
   depends_on:
     - db
     - pipeline_db
     - elasticsearch
```

Is there a way to use Django signals across containers, or should I use an other method to send and receive those messages ?

Thanks

Comment: Django does not send signals to other running processes (instances) it just fires them only for current running instance, it doesn't even know about the existence of other container. You should implement some kind of message queue to notify other container. As far as i understand you are already using celery, so you can pass messages using celery under ` index_post_save` method, to the other container.

Comment: ye, like i said in my anwer, you can use some kind of comunication like API, socket... each server is running in diferent port, if is in same server you probabily keep in mind to setup CORS

Comment: Ok thansk for those answers. Since the containers were using the same database I thought there was a way to make the signals work between both.
I think I'll go with the celery solution

Answer (score 0):

Wait what? the signals works only inside the django project, the most external point that one signal can reach is when they run the command save() inside the methods and check if database saved it or not...

What you can do is run some python code in your terminal, or API, or socket or any comunication that you want to talk backends your backends.

So giveing a shot you can make one API to your pipeline upstream(i dont know much what is it) to be able to receive some POST or GET method, and setup your Backend to send one request to your app (in other container) to receive the data that you want... you can use `requests` or `curl`

im considering that you are using 2 servers in different containers